# Flex: Align two items side by side without max width

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

I don't know if this is possible with flex but what i need is a list with two items side by side and the width per item depends on the content. Like here:

```
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">Item 1 with text</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2 with more text</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3 with some text</div>
  <div class="item">Item 4 without text</div>
  <div class="item">Item 5 lorem</div>
  <div class="item">Item 6 ipsum</div>
  <div class="item">Item 7 with lorem</div>
  <div class="item">Item 8 with ipsum</div>
</div>

.items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  align-self: flex-end;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #e0ddd5;
  color: #171e42;
  padding: 10px;
}

.item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: darkgrey;
}
```

How can i realise that always two items are side by side no matter how many li items i have? There is no outer container that limits the width. I don't want to use float. Is there a flexible solution with grid template columns?

Final result like this (but aligned to the right):

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with floats? This looks like an ideal place for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to [theAlexandrian's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48885837/2827823) answer, and if you can add an inner wrapper, here is an option, where you use the inner `div`, displayed as `inline-block`, for styling, e.g. padding etc.

*Since we deal with inline elements, they, like characters, can have a space between them. One way is to take it out using a negative margin, and here is a few more options:*

- [*How do I remove the space between inline-block elements?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-do-i-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

*Note, since the space width is based on the font, the negative margin might need an adjustment.*

---

Stack snippet

```css
.items {
  text-align: right;
}

.item {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: -4px;        /*  take out inline element space  */
}

.item div {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #e0ddd5;
  color: #171e42;
  padding: 10px;
}

.item:nth-child(even) div {
  background-color: darkgrey;
}

.item:nth-child(even)::after {
  content: '\A';
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item"><div> Item 1 with text </div></div>
  <div class="item"><div> Item 2 with more text </div></div>
  <div class="item"><div> Item 3 with some text </div></div>
  <div class="item"><div> Item 4 without text </div></div>
  <div class="item"><div> Item 5 lorem </div></div>
  <div class="item"><div> Item 6 ipsum </div></div>
  <div class="item"><div> Item 7 with lorem </div></div>
  <div class="item"><div> Item 8 with ipsum </div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thx for this example! Yes i had to set font-size: 0 because of inline-block ;)

Comment: I'd vote up but my vote quota is finished for today. I've been too generous. Maybe tomorrow :) Nice fix

Answer (score 1):

If `float` is forbidden, I do have a simple solution for you! :)
We will use `inline`, `block`, `:nth-child` and `::after`.

There we go:

```css
.item {
  display: inline;
}

.item:nth-child(2n)::after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">Item 1 with text</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2 with more text</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3 with some text</div>
  <div class="item">Item 4 without text</div>
  <div class="item">Item 5 lorem</div>
  <div class="item">Item 6 ipsum</div>
  <div class="item">Item 7 with lorem</div>
  <div class="item">Item 8 with ipsum</div>
</div>
```

**Simple**, isn't it?

Comment: if you add a padding to the .item class everything will overlap. seems to be that the float is the "best" for this...

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried css columns?

```css
.items {
  columns: 2
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">Item 1 with text</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2 with more text</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3 with some text</div>
  <div class="item">Item 4 without text</div>
  <div class="item">Item 5 lorem</div>
  <div class="item">Item 6 ipsum</div>
  <div class="item">Item 7 with lorem</div>
  <div class="item">Item 8 with ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Comment: with columns the items are not correct side by side it should be item 1 and item 2 side by side and the width of each item depends on the content...

Comment: Can you provide an image of what you expect the results to be?

Comment: Image added see top :)

Comment: Why don't you want to use float? seems like a perfectly reasonable solution for this.

Comment: because i was looking for a smart solution without any floats...but if there is no other way i had to use it.